# How to form binary matrix with constants and given probability?

Tags: matrix, probability-or-statistics

I want to create a binary matrix of 6x3 in which six elements (m13,m23, m33, m42, m52, m61) are constant and assigned '0' value; whereas for other twelve elements (m11, m12, m21, m22, m31,m32, m41, m43, m51, m53, m62, m63) I want to assign value of "1" with the probability of 0.5. Given below my effort, I had made yet.

```
mat = Table[Subscript[m, i, j], {i, 6}, {j, 3}];
mat // MatrixForm
n = Round[18*0.5];
k = RandomSample[{mat[[1, 1]], mat[[1, 2]], mat[[1, 3]], mat[[2, 1]], 
   mat[[2, 2]], mat[[2, 3]], mat[[3, 1]], mat[[3, 2]], mat[[3, 3]], 
   mat[[4, 1]], mat[[4, 2]], mat[[4, 3]], mat[[5, 1]], mat[[5, 2]], 
   mat[[5, 3]], mat[[6, 1]], mat[[6, 2]], mat[[6, 3]]}, n]
```

Comment: See SparseArray,  RandomInteger, Condition and MemberQ

Answer (score 7):

```
SparseArray[{i_, j_} :>  RandomInteger[{0, 1}] /; j != IntegerLength[7 - i, 2], 
            {6, 3}, a] // MatrixForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Kindly explain it briefly.

Comment: @Mamoona Please read the docs for each function and then ask specifically  about the ones you don't understand

Answer (score 2):

One approach to this problem is to populate the whole matrix `0/1` with equal probabily, then set the desired elements to zero:

```
ReplacePart[ 
  RandomInteger[1 , {6, 3}] ,
     {{1, 3} , {2, 3} , {3, 3}, {4, 2}, {5, 2}, {6,1}} -> 0 ] // MatrixForm
```